# Remove masked items from the figure in seaborn.heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, mask

If one masks certain elements in a `seaborn` heatmap using the `mask` option, the mask plots white space on top of the figure, as can be seen here in this quick example.

```
# generate some random data
x = [np.random.rand() for x in range(0,20)]
y = [np.random.rand() for y in x]
data = pd.DataFrame([x,y]) # cast it into a dataframe
corr = data.corr() # get the correlation values


# generate a mask
mask = []
l = [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False]
for i in range(0,10):
    mask.append([True for x in range(0,20)])
for i in range(0,10):
    mask.append(l)
mask = np.array(mask)

sb.heatmap(corr,mask=mask)
```

[image]

Is there a way to plot the image, so that the masked area is removed from the plot, so that it appears more like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all the columns and rows from the dataframe for which the `mask` is `True` throughout.

```
masked_corr = corr.loc[~np.all(mask, axis=1), ~np.all(mask, axis=0)]
sns.heatmap(masked_corr)
```

will produce

[image]

Comment: Such an obvious solution. I was thinking absolutely wrong. Thank you